# Bode plot of transfer function with vs without feedback

Tags: transfer-function, bode

I am looking at some old exams. Particularly, one question where there is a Bode plot of a transfer function $G(s)$, and some questions about the Bode plot. So far so good. However, part b) of the question starts asking questions about when the transfer function has feedback. The solutions seem to indicate that the Bode plot does not change when applying feedback.

---

[image: block diagram]

---

How will the Bode plot of the system in the picture look compared to the Bode plot of $G(s)$? I know that the transfer function of the system is $$F(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)}$$ How does that change the bode plot? Will the Bode plot of $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ be the same?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the solutions seem to indicate that the solutions are the same?

Comment: What if $G(s) = j1$ for $s = j\omega$.  Does $F(s) = G(s)$ in that case?